# error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '<' when using template classes

Tags: templates, inheritance

I've inherited stack and queue for my Stack and Queue template classes.

---

```
template<class T>
class Stack : public stack<T> {
```

// My code here
    };

```
template<class T>
class Queue : public queue<T> {
```

//My code here

```
};
```

---

But when I try to compile this code on visual studio 2014 then I get this error for both the lines where I'm using

```
:public stack<T>{
:public queue<T>{
```

If I remove  then it compile without any error.

I tried searching for the solutions online but none of them worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

So the error was because of missing std:: before using stack and queue.

class Stack: public std::stack{
class Queue: public std::queue{

because I had not written "using namespace std;" in my header file so I must mention std:: before every new structure from the built-in library.